# BQ API :: query vs insert ('query') job

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking at BQ API docs: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/ and would like to confirm what's the difference between

**Jobs: query** POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/queries

**Jobs: insert (with a 'query' job)** POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/jobs

Both seem to be serving same purpose, querying a table with provided SQL statement...

Did I understand correctly that:

- one return the query results (data) immediately in it's response body, (sort of synchronous / blocking process)
- whereas other just creates a query job in the backend, (sort of async / non-blocking process) and later we still have to execute either **Jobs: getQueryResults** (if we got jobId) or **Tabledata: list** in order to fetch query results (data).. both of which I believe work in same way (sync / blocking) as **Jobs: query**?!

Thanks a lot!

Cheers!

Comment: Yes, you have explained the difference correctly. Note that for most purposes, you probably want to use a [client library](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries), so you don't need to worry about the details of the REST API.

Comment: Thanks! yeah was just confirming.. always good to know how things work underneath the hood ;). I posted another clarification re: Client Library as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51072806/bq-py-client-libraries-client-run-async-query-vs-client-run-sync-query if you can clarify that as well pls.. Cheers!

Comment: I'm not familiar with that change, but hopefully someone else can help. For this question, consider structuring it such that the "question" is how `jobs.query` and `jobs.insert` are different, then add an answer with an explanation (as you have already written).

Comment: Hello, please can you provide the answer to your question as an answer? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

so my understanding was correct:

`Jobs: query POST`one return the query results (data) immediately in it's response body (sort of synchronous / blocking process)

`Jobs: insert (with a 'query' job) POST` just creates a query job in the backend, (sort of async / non-blocking process) and later we still have to execute either Jobs: getQueryResults (if we got jobId) or Tabledata: list in order to fetch query results (data).. both of which I believe work in same way (sync / blocking) as Jobs: query