# BQ PY Client Libraries :: client.run_async_query() vs client.run_sync_query()

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm looking at [BQ PY Client Libraries](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/bigquery/usage.html#queries):

There used to be two different operations to query a table

```
client.run_async_query()

client.run_sync_query()
```

But in the latest version (v1.3) it seems there's only one operations to execute a query, `Client.query()`. Did I understand correctly?

And looking at [GH code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/ebf80815f17b2f9878b6bdca753f60ca1fdd22ae/bigquery/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py#L1120) it looks `Client.query()` just returns the query job, not the actual query results / data.... Making me conclude it works in a similar way as `client.run_async_query()`.. there's no replacement for `client.run_sync_query()` operation anymore which return query results (data) synchronously / immediately?

Thanks for the clarification!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Although .run_sync_query() has been removed, the [Query reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/#Jobs) says that short jobs may return results right away if they don't take long to finish:

```
query   POST /projects/projectId/queries 

Runs a BigQuery SQL query and returns results if the query completes within a specified timeout.
```

Comment: Thanks for clarification. Basically, if I understand well, there's not Client Library method that we can use to access this API `bigquery.jobs.query` all. (or use REST API directly..)  The only one Client.query() uses `bigquery.jobs.insert` POST  /projects/projectId/jobs under the hood